# erase texture off of plane

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a texture applied to a plane, and would like on screen touch to erase the selected location on that plane (like an eraser) so that in the location i have touched, the texture should be transparent. How can i do so?

Comment: Are you looking for code on how to dynamically change a texture's alpha at certain pixels or are you looking for code to convert a finger touch to the correct X/Y pixel location on said texture?

Comment: @Jerdak code to change dynamically the texture's alpha at certain pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your clarification in the comments above will this work:

```
Texture2D texture = renderer.material.mainTexture;
Color color = new Color(0.5F, 0.5f, 0.5F, 0.5F);  //example color, grey w/ half opacity

texture.SetPixel(0,0,color); //set pixel (0,0) to the color specified
texture.Apply();  //Must be called at least once after all changes to pixels made
```

Hopefully that's what you need.  Obviously you'll need to add the code to modify only pixels near to where your cursor hits.